# binary tree: finding the best results in it

Tags: binary-tree

I have a binary tree which nodes(and root) holds int vals, and it's leafs contain vals which represents prices. 
The node's int vals represents how many leafs in it's sub-tree can be taken in the calculation.
I have to tell what is the biggest sum of prices I can get out of this tree.

I thought at first to get all of the leafs in linkedlist and then start to filter them by their parents values, but it doesn't seem to be the best solution.

any ideas?!

Comment: What do you mean by "biggest sum"? Do you mean largest sum of prices from any selection/combination of leaves of a given root node?

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfLeaves( Node n ){
    int intVal = 0;
    if( n.Left != null ){ intVal += numberOfLeaves(n.Left); }
    if( n.Right != null ){ intVal += numberOfLeaves(n.Right); }
    if( n.Left == null && n.Right == null ){ return 1; }
    return intVal;
}
```

For the biggest sum, just push all of the leaves into a list and sum all of the positive prices if I understand "biggest sum" correctly.